# redirect to a new temporary page using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

i have a forum community at this address

```
http://www.mywebpage.com/forum
```

im going to close for 3 days for big maintenance (new forum, import, etc...) and i want to redirect the user to a temporary page were they can be informed of the update

```
http://www.mywebpage.com/index2.php
```

This is what i've tried with no success...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://www\.mywebpage\.com/forum.* [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www\.mywebpage\.com/index2.php [L]
```

How can I temporary redirect (HTTP 302) to the temporary page?

Comment: Just an addendum, if you worry about your forum being indexed by google (and others), you want a temporary redirect: HTTP 302

Comment: @enapupe thanks for the tip, i will add it to my question

Comment: Is this a Must to use .htaccess only? Because doing so in php and .htaccess is easier for me

Comment: no, it's not a must... as long as it works and i have access to the php file were the code will go

Answer (score 0):

got it! found the answer here:

http://perishablepress.com/htaccess-redirect-maintenance-page-site-updates/

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/index2.php$
RewriteRule ^forum/.*$ /index2.php [R=302,L]
```